# how to change the background and variables in processing from another thread

Tags: java, processing

I'm working on Othello game using processing 3.0 and I'm making a PC vs player mode

So I have to send a task to another thread (for when the PC plays)
this task use variables from the main thread so the process is not working 
(no nothing happened when the PC play)

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e){}
        PcPlay();
    }
});
t.start();
```

Comment: Please improve your question. Are you getting any errors? What does the method `PcPlay()` actually do? How do you test it to see what it is in fact doing? Can you provide more context about the structure of your program and more background into your problem? The better we can understand your problem and code, the better we are able to help.

Comment: Also  I've formatted your code for readability because as posted your code formatting was terrible. In the future I strongly recommend that you do this yourself. Formatting is very important because if your code is not in a standard accepted format, it's not very readable, and if it's not readable, it's not understandable.

Comment: What has this code got to do with "processing"? Looks like regular java.

Comment: i'm not getting errors ,the PcPlay function should update the background of the programe but nothing change when the PcPlay is executed in anther thread

Comment: i'm not getting errors ,the PcPlay function should update the background of the programe but nothing change when the PcPlay is executed in anther thread @HovercraftFullOfEels Full Of Eels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** a job for threading.

Processing already called `draw()` for you 60 times per second. Use that to implement your game logic.

A simple approach would be to simply have a `boolean` variable that keeps track of whose turn it is: the human player or the computer player. If it's the computer player's turn, have the computer take its turn and then flip the variable. If it's the human player's turn, wait for the human to take their turn and then flip the variable again.

If you can't get it working, please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (note: not your full sketch, but not a disconnected snippet either), and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: I've  tried  thread.sleep between the 2 turn  but the program block  that's why i'm using another thread

Comment: and i'm not using draw

Comment: @DelassiOthmane If you aren't using the `draw()` function, why are you using Processing? Again, this is not a job for threading. You only need a single thread to accomplish your goal.

Comment: i have to use processing ,my problem is when the player play i have to wait for 1 second before the pc can play the purpose of wait is the player can see his move before the pc can play  so i add thread.sleep before the PcPlay function but the program block that's why  i'm using another thread

Comment: @DelassiOthmane If you're using Processing, I don't understand why you're not using the `draw()` function. It has everything you need. Again, this is **not** a job for threading. You can create a delay using a simple timeout using either the `millis()` function or the `frameCount` variable.